# Create a Powershell reference in JScript

Tags: powershell, jscript, activexobject

I have written a rather long JScript which needs to run a Powershell script to execute a couple of cmd-lets to gather the current users mail-address from the active directory and return it to my script.

```
var WSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var PowerShellExec = WSH.exec("powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command \"$WNT = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network;$ADSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher;$ADSearcher.Filter = 'name=' + $WNT.UserName;$User = $ADSearcher.FindOne();$UserMail = $User.Properties.Item('mail');Write-Output $UserMail\"");
PowerShellExec.StdIn.Close();
while (PowerShellExec.Status == WshRunning)
{
    WScript.Sleep(10);
}
var UserMail = PowerShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll(); //Data stored in $SomeValue
```

My problem is, that there is a brief moment when a PowerShell window pops up. I would like to avoid that to keep my script silent. The "-WindowStyle Hidden" parameter does not fully avoid that.

Is there some Powershell ActiveXObject that could be used for that purpose instead?

I was hoping for something like...

```
var PSSession = new ActiveXObject("Powershell.Application");
PSSession.code = "...";
PSSession.run();
var Result = PSSession.ReadAll();
```

I know I could use WSH.run to hide my Powershell window completely, but then I need to write my output to some text file before reading from it again. Personally I dislike work arounds like that...

Comment: Is there a reason for combining scripting languages instead of settling on just PowerShell?

Comment: Yes, every language has it's strengths and weaknesses and for some reason Powershell appears to be somewhat unreliable when catching internet explorer events, which however works just fine in jscript. And since like 90% of my code is about interacting with the IE I chose not to code in Powershell in this case.

Comment: For the "I was hoping for something like" part of your question: PowerShell does not have an automation interface that you can call from WSH; sorry. If you insist on using a WSH script instead of PowerShell, I would recommend querying AD from your WSH script instead of externally running PowerShell. Alternatively (as suggested already), redesign using PowerShell and dispense with the WSH script. (Don't know what you mean by "somewhat unreliable.")

Comment: Another reason why I dislike Powershell in this case is that you can't run it completely silent (the main purpose of this thread was to completely avoid a Powershell window from popping up shortly) while WSH can either have a console (CScript) or runs fully in the background (WScript) without being noticed by the user at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
var codepage='windows-1251';/*US-Europe-1252 and Js file in that codepage*/
var toPStext='Hello.\nПроверка русских буковок.';
var shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
var std=shell.Exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command \
    $OutputEncoding = [Console]::outputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('"+codepage+"'); \
    Write-Output '"+toPStext+"'");
var output = std.StdOut.ReadAll().split('\r\n');// split('\n') - приводит к потере части данных leads to the loss of some data
if (output.length>0){WScript.echo(output)}
var x=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This helped me answering my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68678633/1970139.