# How can I solve this special character encoding problem between VBA and Powershell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, encoding

For a larger vba application I need to use powershell scripts to give me the filenames on a share. As I live in Germany, these filenames contain a lot of german special characters like **ü**, **ä**, and so on.

The output of the powershell script, that should (and on the PS Console does) display those characters correctly is **not** displayed correctly in VBA. I've made up this minimal example to demonstrate this.

Any solution that gives back **für** instead of **fr** is appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Const HK = """"

Sub ScanDrive()
    Dim s As String, command As String
   
    command = "echo 'für'"
    Debug.Print (command)
    'Method1: start PS in CMD with /u parameter
    s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").exec("cmd /u /c powershell.exe -command " & HK & command & HK).StdOut.ReadAll
    Debug.Print (s)
    'Method2: start PS directly (preferred)
    s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").exec("powershell.exe -command " & HK & command & HK).StdOut.ReadAll
    Debug.Print (s)
End Sub
```

My output looks like this (though vba doesn't display the `````` character at all):

```
echo 'für'
fr

fr
```

I've already learned that I can change the PS output encoding when I'm writing to a file-output. Unfortunately this will not be an option.

In my understanding I'd have to make Excel read UTF-8 (I guess, that's what it is) or make the PS Console write out Win-1252 (also just a guess, that this is, what Excel uses).

As I have to deploy this script in a company I cannot rely on any global switches for the PS Console.

**Update**

According to JosefZ 's comment I put the command as `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` and got the following in VBA:

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : ibm850
EncodingName      : Westeurop„isch (DOS)
HeaderName        : ibm850
WebName           : ibm850
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 850
```

as opposed to running it directly in the powershell where it states:

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Westeuropäisch (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

The `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")` seems to work on Dos encoding and CP850.

Comment: I'd guess that `$OutputEncoding`, `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` and `[System.Console]::InputEncoding` must be in accordance with _VBA_ script encoding (or inner Excel one?)…

Comment: @JosefZ, thanks for the insight in those commands. I updated the question adding the output of those commands.

Comment: Not an answer but I found this interesting and might be useful to you: https://francescofoti.com/2020/01/solving-the-unicode-utf8-utf16-and-text-files-conundrum-in-vba/

Comment: Nice question/answer; +1. However, would you be willing to edit the question title to be more precise for the question? (something with encoding special characters mentioned) as I believe it could potentially help more people in the future that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, I found the solution.

[JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz)'s comment put me on the right track and led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67301963/1970139) underrated answer from [Garric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1808515/garric) to another question.

Adapted his solution to my original minimal example code gives this:

```vb
Option Explicit
Const HK = """"

Sub ScanDrive()
    Dim s As String, command As String
    Dim codepage As String
    codepage = "windows-1252"
    command = "$OutputEncoding = [Console]::outputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('" + codepage + "'); echo 'für'"
    Debug.Print (command)
    s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("powershell.exe -command " & HK & command & HK).StdOut.ReadAll
    Debug.Print (s)
End Sub
```

Et Voilá - We have our german Umlauts correctly :)

Comment: Something else that might be confusing: If you run this command in powershell it errors that you cannot assign to one of those variables. Leaving either of the assignees out fixes the error, but then it doesn't work out of vba. As we do not consume the Stderr, i think this is still fine.